# How can I set the two-bit rounding control (RC) field of the FPU control word to 10 (round towards +infinity) using GAS in C

Tags: c, x87

How can I set the two-bit rounding control (RC) field of the FPU control word to 10 (round towards +infinity) using GAS in C.

Must use format

```
asm(

);
```

should only be about 7 lines of code altogether.

first push RC register onto the stack, flip the bits so that bit 10 & 11 are turned "on"

I'm unsure how to write this in the floating point stack using the correct syntax.

[image: Code Image]

Comment: Better to post your code here, as text.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)